org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException
Tried to upgrade Flink version from 1.14.2 to 1.17.1 for an already running application. The application has source and  sink as Kafka (different topics same cluster). After upgrading the version the following error was thrown.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: Cannot create a v0 FindCoordinator      request because we require features supported only in 2 or later.

Tried updating the kafka-clients version from 1.1.1 to 2.0.0 but still the error persists.
<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId> <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId> <version>2.0.0</version> </dependency>

The Flink Kafka connector for Flink 1.17.1 uses version 3.2.3 of the Kafka Clients, as you can see in the source code at https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.17.1/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/pom.xml#L38
You will need to upgrade to that version.
